# Firebase | How to get the sum of all child entries

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The problem when one item value increases the time calculation wrong because the sum value already store. Example: 3 item--- 2+2+2=6 that's right. when 1st item value increases that time 4+2+2=14 (8+previous 6).

Can you help me?

Main focusable part

```
private void caculatateprice(){
        String cccex= uid+"_"+"calculate";
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.exists()) {
                    int itemTotalPrice = 0;
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.child(uid).getChildren()) {
                        Map<String, Object> tp = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                        Object price = tp.get("itemtotalprice");
                        itemTotalPrice = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(price));

                        subTotal += itemTotalPrice;
                        finalTotalPrice = subTotal + extraCharge;
                        subtotal.setText("$" + String.valueOf(subTotal));
                        deliveryCharge.setText("$" + String.valueOf(extraCharge));
                        totalPrice.setText("$" + String.valueOf(finalTotalPrice));
                    }
                }
            }
```

> java

```
public class CartFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Button checkOutButton;
    private CartItemAdapter itemAdapter;
    private ArrayList<CartItemModel> cartItemList;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private String uid;
    private TextView subtotal,deliveryCharge,totalPrice;
    private int subTotal=0,extraCharge=1,finalTotalPrice=0;
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.cartrecycler);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        uid = user.getUid();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("carts");

        GetDataFromFirebase();
        checkOutButton = view.findViewById(R.id.checkoutbutton);

        subtotal = view.findViewById(R.id.subtotalprice);
        deliveryCharge = view.findViewById(R.id.deliveryprice);
        totalPrice = view.findViewById(R.id.producttotalprice);
        caculatateprice();
    }

    private void caculatateprice(){
        String cccex= uid+"_"+"calculate";
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.exists()) {
                    int itemTotalPrice = 0;
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.child(uid).getChildren()) {
                        Map<String, Object> tp = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                        Object price = tp.get("itemtotalprice");
                        itemTotalPrice = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(price));

                        subTotal += itemTotalPrice;
                        finalTotalPrice = subTotal + extraCharge;
                        subtotal.setText("$" + String.valueOf(subTotal));
                        deliveryCharge.setText("$" + String.valueOf(extraCharge));
                        totalPrice.setText("$" + String.valueOf(finalTotalPrice));
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void GetDataFromFirebase() {

        Query query = databaseReference.child(uid);
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ClearAll();
                for(DataSnapshot  snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    CartItemModel productItem = new CartItemModel();
                    productItem.setImage(snapshot.child("image").getValue().toString());
                    productItem.setName(snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString());
                    productItem.setPrice(snapshot.child("price").getValue().toString());
                    productItem.setProductId(snapshot.child("productId").getValue().toString());
                    productItem.setQuantity(snapshot.child("quantity").getValue().toString());
                    productItem.setItemtotalprice(snapshot.child("itemtotalprice").getValue().toString());

                    cartItemList.add(productItem);
                }
                itemAdapter = new CartItemAdapter(getActivity(),cartItemList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
                itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }

        });
    }

    private void ClearAll(){
        if (cartItemList!=null){
            cartItemList.clear();
            if (itemAdapter!=null){
                itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        cartItemList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Adapter class

```
public class CartItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartItemAdapter.CartItemViewHolder> {

    private int intquantity,itemTotalPrice,itemprice,subTotal,extraCharge=1,finalTotalPrice;
    String cartId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("carts").child(cartId);
    DatabaseReference databaseReference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("carts");
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<CartItemModel> cartItem;
    public CartItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CartItemModel> cartItem) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cartItem = cartItem;


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CartItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cart_item_card, parent, false);
        return new CartItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String ccc= cartId+"_"+cartItem.get(position).getProductId();
//        String cccex= cartId+"_"+"calculate";

        holder.itemname.setText(cartItem.get(position).getName());
        holder.itemprice.setText("$"+cartItem.get(position).getPrice());
        Glide.with(context).load(cartItem.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.itemimage);
        holder.quantityitem.setText(cartItem.get(position).getQuantity());
        holder.itemtotalprice.setText("$"+cartItem.get(position).getItemtotalprice());

        holder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String quantity = cartItem.get(position).getQuantity();
                intquantity =Integer.parseInt(quantity.toString());

                String itemPrice = cartItem.get(position).getPrice();
                itemprice =Integer.parseInt(itemPrice.toString());

                if(intquantity>0){
                    intquantity--;
                }
                itemTotalPrice = intquantity*itemprice;
                HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
                result.put("quantity", intquantity);
                result.put("itemtotalprice",itemTotalPrice);

                databaseReference.child(ccc).updateChildren(result)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            }
                        });

//                subTotal = subTotal+itemTotalPrice;
//                finalTotalPrice=subTotal+extraCharge;
//                HashMap<String, Object> totalresult = new HashMap<>();
//                totalresult.put("subtotal", subTotal);
//                totalresult.put("totalprice",finalTotalPrice);
//
//                databaseReference1.child(cccex).updateChildren(totalresult)
//                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
//                            @Override
//                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
//
//                            }
//                        });
            }
        });
        holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String quantity = cartItem.get(position).getQuantity();
                intquantity =Integer.parseInt(quantity.toString());

                String itemPrice = cartItem.get(position).getPrice();
                itemprice =Integer.parseInt(itemPrice.toString());

                intquantity++;
                itemTotalPrice = intquantity*itemprice;
                HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
                result.put("quantity", intquantity);
                result.put("itemtotalprice",itemTotalPrice);

                databaseReference.child(ccc).updateChildren(result)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            }
                        });
//                subTotal = subTotal+itemTotalPrice;
//                finalTotalPrice=subTotal+extraCharge;
//                HashMap<String, Object>totalresult = new HashMap<>();
//                totalresult.put("subtotal", subTotal);
//                totalresult.put("totalprice",finalTotalPrice);
//
//                databaseReference1.child(cccex).updateChildren(totalresult)
//                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>(){
//                            @Override
//                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid){
//
//                            }
//                        });
            }
        });
        holder.cross.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                databaseReference.child(ccc).removeValue();
                Toast.makeText(context,"Item Removed from Cart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                cartItem.remove(position);
                notifyItemChanged(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cartItem.size();
    }

    public static final class CartItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView itemname, itemprice, quantityitem, itemtotalprice;
        private ImageView itemimage, minus, plus, cross;

        public CartItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            itemprice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
            itemimage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
            quantityitem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemcount);
            itemtotalprice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemtotalprice);
            minus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemminus);
            plus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemplus);
            cross = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemdelete);
        }
    }
}
```

> database

```
{
  "carts" : {
    "6OD9qfVX9LMN4CoWb6qmSJvXTlf2" : {
      "6OD9qfVX9LMN4CoWb6qmSJvXTlf2_1002" : {
        "id" : "6OD9qfVX9LMN4CoWb6qmSJvXTlf2_1002",
        "image" : "https://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/i/z/i/HMTe-HM-9072-Metal-Analog-SDL494827480-1-db8fc.jpg",
        "itemtotalprice" : "390",
        "name" : "Metal Analog",
        "price" : "390",
        "productId" : "1002",
        "quantity" : "1"
      },
      "6OD9qfVX9LMN4CoWb6qmSJvXTlf2_1008" : {
        "id" : "6OD9qfVX9LMN4CoWb6qmSJvXTlf2_1008",
        "image" : "https://cdn4.ethoswatches.com/the-watch-guide/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Top-10-Casio-G-Shock-Watches-Post-mobile-mast.jpg",
        "itemtotalprice" : "80",
        "name" : "G-Shock(casio)",
        "price" : "80",
        "productId" : "1008",
        "quantity" : "1"
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: It is very hard to understand the question without seeing a [minimal complete reproduction of the code that we all can run to get the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please don't post code blocks in comments. Instead, click the edit link under your question, and then use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to make your code readable.

Comment: Please don't post code links to code. Instead, click the edit link under your question, and then use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to make your code readable. –

Comment: I was asking questions for the first time so I couldn’t add. Now, I've successfully added the code. can you help now? thanks for your response.

Comment: Please read the link I provided in my first comment again, as there really is way too much code here. For example: can you reproduce the problem by just `Log.i`'ing the value? If so, do that and you can remove the XML and views from the question. Do you really need `CartItemModel`, or can you also get the same problem without it? If so, remove `CartItemModel` from the question. Finally: include the JSON at `databaseReference` in your question (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your Firebase Database console.